# Invocation command using SSH getting failed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, unzip

As per project requirement, i need to check the content of zip file generated which been generated on remote machine.This entire activity is done using automation framework suites. which has been written in shell scripts. I am performing above activity using ssh command abd execute unzip command with -l and -q switches. But this command is getting failed. and shows below error messages.

```
[SOMEUSER@MACHINE IP Function]$ ./TESTS.sh
    ssh SOMEUSER@MACHINE IP unzip -l -q SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip | grep -i XML  |wc -l
    unzip:  cannot find or open SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip, SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip.zip or SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip.ZIP.

    No zipfiles found.
    0
```

the same command i had written manually  but that works properly. I really have no idea.Why this is getting failed whenever i executed via shell scripts.

```
[SOMEUSER@MACHINE IP Function]$ ssh SOMEUSER@MACHINE IP unzip -l -q SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip | grep -i XML  |wc -l
        2
```

Kindly help me to resolve that issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Priyank Shah

Comment: This got resolved, Since on remote zip creation is taking fraction amount of time and execution of ssh command is quite fast. so while triggering ssh command doesn't file find zip at that location. so i put sleep between two statements.now that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run the command from your local machine, the asterisk character is being expanded on your local machine before it is passed on to your remote ssh command. So your command is expecting to find SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip files on your machine and insert them into your ssh command to be passed to the other machine, whereas you (I'm assuming) mean, SOME_PATH/20130409060734*.zip files on the remote machine.

for that, precede the * character by a backslash ( \ ) and see if it helps you. In some shells escape character might be defined differently and if yours is one of them you need to find the escape character and use that one instead. Also, use quotes around the commands being passed to other server. Your command line should look something like this in my opinion:

```
ssh SOMEUSER@MACHINE_IP "/usr/bin/unzip -l -q SOME_PATH/20130409060734\*.zip | grep -i XML  |wc -l"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks For Suggestion, I tried all changes you mentioned, 1. Given Prefix backslash to * and 2) Given whole path of unzip executable. But still getting same error.

Comment: please execute `ssh remote_host "ls -l SOME_PATH" | grep -i zip` and post the output by editing your question.